# How to attach event handler in backbone forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-forms

I am using Backbone form - https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms.

In few fields I am using custom template for a specific field. Lets say something like this

[image]

Now Lets say I want to attach a click event handler to "Add month". What is the best way to accomplish it. I see that Backbone.Form is extending Backbone.View which has accepts events object. But when I pass that while doing
new Backbone.Form() it does't do anything.

Comment: Can you provide the source or a https://jsfiddle.net/ showing your problem?

Comment: @akoskm - here  http://jsfiddle.net/40qysLL3/1/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to extend the Backbone.Form view to add your own custom events, like this

```
Backbone.Form.extend({
    events: _.extend(this.events, {
      'click .add-month': 'onClickAddMonth' 
    }),

    onClickAddMonth: function(e){
       // do something
    }
})
```